# Writing a BytesIO object to a file, 'efficiently'

Tags: python, io, bytesio

So a quick way to write a BytesIO object to a file would be to just use:

```
with open('myfile.ext', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(myBytesIOObj.getvalue())
myBytesIOObj.close()
```

However, if I wanted to iterate over the myBytesIOObj as opposed to writing it in one chunk, how would I go about it? I'm on Python 2.7.1. Also, if the BytesIO is huge, would it be a more efficient way of writing by iteration?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`shutil` has a utility that will write the file efficiently. It copies in chunks, defaulting to 16K. Any multiple of 4K chunks should be a good cross platform number. I chose 131072 rather arbitrarily because really the file is written to the OS cache in RAM before going to disk and the chunk size isn't that big of a deal.

```
import shutil

myBytesIOObj.seek(0)
with open('myfile.ext', 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(myBytesIOObj, f, length=131072)
```

BTW, there was no need to close the file object at the end.  `with` defines a scope, and the file object is defined inside that scope.  The file handle is therefore closed automatically on exit from the `with` block.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. This works perfectly. And yes, I'll not bother closing my file pointer. However, my Bytes/String IO pointer, I want to close, in effect, discarding it and letting it go to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 12):

Since Python 3.2 it's possible to use the [BytesIO.getbuffer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getbuffer) method as follows:

```py
from io import BytesIO
buf = BytesIO(b'test')
with open('path/to/file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(buf.getbuffer())
```

This way it doesn't copy the buffer's content, streaming it straight to the open file.

Note: The `StringIO` buffer doesn't support the `getbuffer()` protocol (as of Python 3.9).

Before streaming the `BytesIO` buffer to file, you might want to set its position to the beginning:

```
buf.seek(0)
```